# jquery javascript get checkbox's initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a check box and want to get the very inital value or in other words get the default value just like we get the default value of a text box as follows:

```
 document.getElementById("myTextBoxID").defaultValue
```

I want to do the something similar either using jQuery/JS

```
 document.getElementById("myChkBoxID").defaultValue
```

So if I get a checkbox value checked from the server the very first time...now whenever the user changes the checkbox ...i should have a way of restoring it back to the very inital state

Is it possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `defaultChecked` property.

`defaultChecked` and `defaultValue` are [defined in DOM level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html) as follows:

> defaultChecked of type boolean
>
> When type has the value "radio" or "checkbox", this represents the HTML checked attribute
> of the element. The value of this attribute does not change if the state of the
> corresponding form control, in an interactive user agent, changes. See the checked
> attribute definition in HTML 4.01.
>
> defaultValue of type DOMString
>
> When the type attribute of the element has the value "text", "file" or "password", this
> represents the HTML value attribute of the element. The value of this attribute does not
> change if the contents of the corresponding form control, in an interactive user agent,
> changes. See the value attribute definition in HTML 4.01.

Note that a checkbox does have a value attribute which you can change, but it is usually not something you would want, and can cause hard-to-find bugs...

Alternatives:

Since you are letting the server set the initial value, you can include a hidden input field and let the server set the initial state on it.

Or you can [reset](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml) the entire form.

Comment: I dont want to use hidden fields...is it possible using javascript/jquery??The reson being if I have 1000 checkboxes with different values...i would need 1000 hidden fields

Comment: Exactly what I need....thanks...grat man!!!thanks..Ill accept when I am allowed to do so..

Comment: In the end it's also very logical; the 'checked' attribute is not called 'value' :-)

Comment: @graphicdivine Why is that? It gives a nice example on the usage. BTW I added the W3C definition later.

Comment: @graphicdivine ok, I removed the link. It's a pity though that W3C do not have an easy-to-use reference (with examples) hosted themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
    document.getElementById("myChkBoxID").defaultChecked
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement

Comment: `$('#myChkBoxID')[0].defaultChecked`. If this works in IE, you get my upvote. Didn't know about that property.

Comment: @Blender Thanks.  It does. DOM Level 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the data when the page loads:

```
$(function() {
  $(':input').each(function() {
    $(this).data('default', $(this).val());
  });
});
```

Now, for any `<input />` element, you can get its default value easily:

```
$('#yourInputElement').data('default');
```

When you want to reset the element to its default state, just call `val()` once more:

```
$('#yourInputElement').val($('#yourInputElement').data('default'));
```

Comment: But I need it for a checkbox not for a textbox??

Comment: That makes more sense. Lemme do that instead.

Comment: Done. Check my answer once more.

Comment: Okay but guys...i dont want to put load on the application....i know about the hidden and attribute way of doing it..but wanted a S/Jquery way of achieving it if possible?

Comment: How many checkboxes do you *have*? This will run (noticeably laggy) only for thousands.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the default value somehow. In this instance, I would think a data attribute would be acceptable.

```
//onload
$('#textboxID, #checkboxID').each(function(){
    $(this).data('default', $(this).val());
});

//on reset
$('#textboxID, #checkboxID').each(function(){
    $(this).val( $(this).data('default'));
});
```